# Why is the time comparing in sql is not correct using case in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let say my getdate() = 21:57:00

I am not sure why it keep going return me the '1' instead of '3'
I know this should be a simple one. I just do not know what is wrong with the query. Can someone help me on this?

```
select case when  CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),GETDATE(),113) > LTRIM((RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())) + '7:00:00:000',120),20)))  THEN 2
when CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),GETDATE(),113) > LTRIM((RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())) + '15:00:00:000',120),20))) THEN 3
ELSE 1 end as GETCURRENTSHIFTNUMBERCONVERT
```

My expected result should be '3'. I am looking to get the shift number using 24 hours time. Basically if it more than 7:00:00 then it will be 2, if it more than 15:00:00 then it will be 3, so if it is not in the condition, it will become 1. So let say my time is actually 21:45:00, so the number return should be 3.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what you want your code to do.  Sample data and desired results are very helpful.  A SQL Fiddle is a big help as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just using the "hour" portion of the time?

```
select (case when datepart(hour, getdate()) >= 15 then 3
             when datepart(hour, getdate()) >= 7 then 2
             else 1
        end)
```

Note that the ordering of the conditions is important.